# Showing NEST Camera video in a WebView

Tags: android

I have a NEST Camera publishing both web_url and app_url for camera streaming. I am utilising the web_url to stream the camera video using android webView .Below is my code :

```
   nestWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
   nestWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   nestWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
   nestWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   nestWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   nestWebView.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
   nestWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   nestWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   nestWebView.loadUrl(mURL.toString()
```

The above code opens the NEST webpage in WebView in my application , but the camera streaming does not begin.The mUrl looks something like this :

https://home.nest.com/cameras/CjZaRHdCVm.....?auth=850FqA.....

Any ideas what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nest Camera API document there are three types of URL you will get.

1. **web_url** : Web URL (deep link) to the live video stream at home.nest.com.
2. **app_url** : App URL (deep link) to the live video stream in the Nest app.
3. **public_share_url** : You can access this URL when a user makes their video stream public.

So If you are trying to load web_url inside the webview then it will load entire webapp over there.

In my case I just wanted to see Nest Video, so I have enabled public_share_url and implemented in following way.

```
 String iFrameUrl = "https://video.nest.com/embedded/live/Es9Ol5DCCB?autoplay=0";

 WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
 webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
 webView.loadUrl(iFrameUrl);
```